# Deployment of SSIS Package to SQL Server using Jenkins

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, ssis

Can anyone please help me on how to deploy SSIS package to SQL Server using Jenkins.

Also how to deploy .ispac file to SQL Server using Jenkins

Comment: An SSIS project, is the "uncompiled" code, the .ispac is the unit of deployment. msbuild with a custom task is used to compile the packages, project parameters and project connection managers into the ispac. Deployment is generally handled through the isdeploymentwizard.exe.  Do you need the Jenkins bits for both compilation and deployment or just deployment?

Comment: Hi Billinkc I need to do both compile and deployment tasks using Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following link: [SSIS package deployment using Jenkins](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/ssis-2012-continuous-integration-using-jenkins-and-octopus-a-journey-to-db-deployment-automation/)

Comment: I need to deploy SSIS package to SQL server

Comment: Harish ,deployment SSIS package at SQL Server is very easy , Open a deployment wizard and then select .ispac file form the location where currently SSIS is developed .https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/213/deploying-ssis-packages/

Comment: i need to do using Jenkins